# Upload an image as a static resource and reference it Via CSS

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I'm trying to reference an image on my VF page like so:

```
        form {
            margin-top: 5px;
            background-image: url("http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/velka.jpg");
        }
```

I would like to replace the hard coded URL above with a static resource.
I tried following this article: [Referencing a Static Resource in Visualforce Markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm) but I'm not sure how.

Please help

Comment: Just download the image from the url. Then add a static resource as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_create.htm), then follow the tutorial you put in your question.

Comment: The problem of the tutorial that I put in my question is that it says I should upload a stylesheet file and also an image, I don't want to upload a stylesheet, I just need the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this? After having added the image as a static resource of name 'TestImage' for example.

```
form {
            margin-top: 5px;
            background-image: url({!$Resource.TestImage});
        }
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.